# Pelican custom.css not changing font size

Tags: python, pelican

I'm using `THEME = 'bootstrap'` in pelican to generate a static site. I have followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30030492/3904031) which addresses bootstrap3

1. create a custom.css file and put it in an `extras` folder
2. edit `pelicanconf.py` and add three lines

but I don't see any change in font size. Is there something further I need to do to 'invoke' the change? When I edit/corrupt the css file to see if pelican notices, nothing happens, which leads me to believe there is something missing. Any helpful explanations are appreciated - I'm new at this.

I would be happy with just making all font 150% of current size, but targeting some sections would be super.

EDIT: I use restructured text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike `bootstrap3`, `bootstrap` isn't configured to add in custom CSS. So, your `CUSTOM_CSS` setting has no effect.

You need a clone of bootstrap and directly modify the CSS (probably [`local.css`](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/blob/master/bootstrap/static/local.css)). You can place the cloned `bootstrap` anywhere you like and provide the path, either absolute or relative to the settings file, via `THEME` setting.

Comment: Thanks @Avaris! (maybe I should just change to bootstrap3)  Does "clone of bootstrap" mean a copy of the bootstrap folder which I have in the themes folder? In my clone, can I actually just increase the individual font sizes directly?

Comment: @uhoh, yes, I mean your local copy of bootstrap. You probably already have it since you do `THEME = 'bootstrap'`. Just modify the css files inside that.

Answer (score 1):

I also struggle with the same issues, I am using `notmyidea` pelican theme. In this themes, I change the files `output/theme/css/main.css`, and then ghp-import those file to github.io, and then your blog will be changed.
By using the same way, you can also change the css files in `output/theme/css/` directory, maybe its name is not called main.css. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I haven't been doing this for several years now, but it's good to know that you've found something that works for you.